# ios - comparing strings with emoji character

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, emoji, utf8mb4

I have updated my server side code to store utf8mb4 type. In ios I send "[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]" to server by converting to (NSMutableData *)[dataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Now when I get back list of devices, I need to compare names and find which one is current device.

Here I cannot compare if names has emoji in it.

First problem was getting correct length of device name. For 1 emoji character `length` fuction would return 2. Solved it by using

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] / 4
```

Second problem is comaparing with names send by server. Server sends name like "Ipad\Uf643" and

```
NSData *dataenc = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString * deviceName = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataenc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

gives "Ipad\ud83d\ude43"

This are two different forms of same emoji. Python and objective C representation are different.

Then to compare I tried `isEqualToString` , `localizedCompare`. Cannot figure out how to do this. Also "Ipad\Uf643" dispayed as `?`.

Comment: Which Emoji is that supposed to be?  I am having trouble decoding either of your samples.